# EF Code First: Entity type with multiple many-to-one relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Consider 3 classes: `Person`, `Company`, and `File`.

`Person` and `Company` are completely different and unrelated, but they each have a collection of `File` objects. Regardless of what entity it belongs to, `File` always has the same structure.

This question is about how to best model the multiple many-to-one relationships that `File` can have; in this case `File` can have a many-to-one relationship with `Person` or with `Company` (but not both in the same instance).

---

**Approach 1:**

```
class Person
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public ICollection<File> Files {get;set;}
}
class Company
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public ICollection<File> Files {get;set;}
}
class File
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Path {get;set;}
}

/* 
    EF Generates:
    -----------------
    Table: Person (Id)
    Table: Company (Id)
    Table: File (Id, Path, Person_Id, Company_Id)
*/
```

This seems the simplest and most straightforward from a code first perspective, and it's what I like best. The problem is the table `File`, which has null-able fields for Person_Id and Company_Id. From a DB design perspective, this seems wrong, considering that only one of the two fields will ever have a value, and the other will always be null. Adding more classes with file collections exasperates the problem even more.

---

**Approach 2:**

```
class Person
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public ICollection<PersonFile> Files {get;set;}
}
class Company
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public ICollection<CompanyFile> Files {get;set;}
}
class File
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Path {get;set;}
}
class PersonFile
{
    public Person Person {get;set;}
    public File File {get;set;}
}
class CompanyFile
{
    public Company Company {get;set;}
    public File File {get;set;}
}

/*
    EF Generates:
    ------------------
    Table: Person (Id)
    Table: Company (Id)
    Table: File (Id, Path)
    Table: PersonFile (Person_Id, File_Id)
    Table: CompanyFile (Company_Id, File_Id)
*/
```

This accomplishes the same thing as Approach 1, and is closer to what I have traditionally done in DB first design. But it requires two additional classes that I really don't need... or do I? I guess that's the point of this question...

---

**When designing a Code First Entity Framework application, do I need to worry about the database schema? Can I prioritize my code/model simplicity over the database design, as in Approach 1? Or should I write classes with database design in mind, as in Approach 2?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yes you do have to worry about the database schema,

Maybe not specifically in your example, but especially when inheritance is used.

The reason for this is because relational databases (esp. SQL) do not know the concept of inheritance. When designing your schedule you'll have to decide what approach suits your needs.

For example, when creating a school database, you'll probably design a Person, who has a name, address, telephone number, etc.

You'll find that both Students and Teachers have names, addresses etc. In contrast to popular belief you'll find that both students and teachers are persons.

Three approaches to inheritance are most used.

- **TPH** Table per hierarchy: one big table for all derived classes of Person, with all properties of the Teachers and the Students in one table
- **TPT** Table per type: Teachers / Students / Persons are in separate tables. Teachers and Students have a foreign key to their Person data
- **TPC** Table per Concrete class: a Teacher table that contains all data for Teachers and the Person Properties and a Student table that contains all data for Students and Person Properties.

Whichever you'll use depends on the ratio of shared properties and the difference between Students and Teachers. If they have almost all their properties in common, then TPH with one table will be enough.

However if there are a lot of student properties that teachers don't have, then the table will have a lot of null values for teachers. If there aren't a lot of teachers compared to the number of students this might not be a problem, otherwise the waste of space might be an item to consider.

Another thing to consider is how often the scheme will change. If you really are certain that teachers will always be Persons, and that the common properties between Students and Teachers (= Person properties), will always be common, then probably TPH will be better: three tables: Persons / Teachers / Students.

On the other hand, if you think that whenever you need a student, you'll always need his Person data, then TPH will always lead to a join. Perhaps in that case TPC might be a better choice. However, if you quite often only need Student's specific data without his Person data, TPC might not be a good choice

If you don't care about the scheme, you'll find that Entity Framework will choose TPH: one big table with all students and teachers with all properties of students and teachers.

If you don't want this, you'll have to tell EF that you want one of the other approaches. This is easily done using *fluent API*

How this is done is fairly good described in [Inheritance Strategy in Code-First](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inheritance-strategy-in-code-first.aspx)

By the way, the complete article was very helpful for me to start programming using EF - code first

Comment: Thank you! Response and link both very helpful!